# How to remove lists from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have created a list where within it I seek to eliminate only the lists whose first value is greater than the second value of it.

I tried creating a second list with the elements to remove but I think it is not the most optimal way.

```
#y = []

x = [[1, 4], [1, 6], [2, 5], [2, 7], [4, 8], [6, 5], [6, 7], [2, 6], [3, 7], [5, 8], [6, 4], [7, 5]]
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i][0] > x[i][1]:
        print(x[i])


#        y.append(x[i])
```

Is there an optimal way to achieve this?

I want that when printing on screen you get the following:

```
[[1, 4], [1, 6], [2, 5], [2, 7], [4, 8], [6, 7], [2, 6], [3, 7], [ 5, 8]]
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
y = [[a,b] for a,b in x if a <= b]
```

Testing:

```
>>> x = [[1, 4], [1, 6], [2, 5], [2, 7], [4, 8], [6, 5], [6, 7], [2, 6], [3, 7], [5, 8], [6, 4], [7, 5]]
>>> y = [[a,b] for a,b in x if a < b]
>>> y
[[1, 4], [1, 6], [2, 5], [2, 7], [4, 8], [6, 7], [2, 6], [3, 7], [5, 8]]
>>>
```

Comment: Should it be `if a <= b`?

Comment: @JoshuaHall maybe, OP did not say anything about that, but you're right, I made the change =)

Answer (score 0):

This modifies the original list:

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(x):
    if a > b:
        del x[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new list:

```py
[v for v in x if v[0] <= v[1]]
```

Or elimination in place:

```py
for i in range(len(x) - 1, -1, -1):  # need to start at the end
    if x[i][0] > x[i][1]:
        x.pop(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> filtered = list(filter(lambda f: f[0] < f[1], x))
>>> print(filtered)
```

This will create a new list with the desired values, using the built in `filter(function, iterable)` function.